# powershell embedded c# using ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, observablecollection

I am trying to add a type in powershell from c# code that uses an observablecollection.  I've tried for a day or two and I can't get anything to work.

What I was trying to come up with was a view model for wpf without relying on any kind of extra powershell modules.

This is the latest I've come up with:

```
$code = @"

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

        public TestClass()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
    }
}    

"@


Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -ReferencedAssemblies @("WindowsBase") -Language CSharpVersion3
```

I can't get past an error of:

Add-Type : c:\Users\ncollier\AppData\Local\Temp\wjq4ciwc.0.cs(9) : The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found (
are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Edit**
I'm trying to run this in powergui, but if I run it in the powershell ISE maybe it works...  Is there something I could be doing wrong in powergui?

Comment: are you sure that this is your code? i cannot find the definition of the class "Departments" and even if i would - a Collection<Departments> wouldn't fit into a Collection<string>

Comment: I fixed that.  I reduced the code.  It had a Department class but, I'm trying to isolate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try just :

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code
```

In my box I can add type.

Edit after comment:

I discovered that using `powershell.exe.config` ( or for ISE `powershell_ise.exe.config`) to load .net 4.0 there's no needs to add ReferencedAssemblies (in this code, others situations needs reference system.core or may needs others assembly references ). I suspect that also PowerGui load .net 4.0 but I can test it. 
You can try on PowerGui this:

```
 [appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies()
```

and see if there are assemblies version `4.0.xxxx`

Comment: If I use Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code it works in powergui, but not in powershell ISE.  Why would the same code work differently, aren't they both doing the same thing?

Comment: really strange behaviour... on ISE works your commandline.... I thinking about a little hours and I report my deduction here!